# How can I add an image to Javascript after a button click?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm doing a project with buttons that follow commands when they are clicked. The start is an orange box and my commands make it grow, turn blue, fade, or reset. I wanted to add a "surprise" button that replaced the box with an image.

This is one of my commands in JS for `#button5`. I got so far as to remove the box.

```js
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    document.getElementById("box").remove();
  }
);
```

```html
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> -->

<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
<button id="button5">Surprise</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to toggle your image:

```js
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function(){
        var box = document.getElementById("box");
        if(box.style.display !== "none"){
          document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("image").style.display = "block";
          return;
        }
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("image").style.display = "none";
    });
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px">
    </div>
    <img id="image" src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" style="display: none; height:150px; width:150px; margin:25px"></img>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>
    <button id="button5">Surprise</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up adding the image to the html but changed the display to none and then in my JS document I added the image and then changed the display to block and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML with image by [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) in Javascript.

eg `function addImage() {     var newImage=document.getElementById('myBox');     newImage.innerHTML = '<img src="image.jpg" alt="image">';     console.log("add image"); }`

Comment: Do not add link-only answers. Please provide an example for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the complete box just remove the orange color, and create a new img tag to insert an image in the same div tag.

Also, whenever clicking on any other button, just remove the img tag.

Added, click event for two buttons to show the behavior.

```js
document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "";
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "");  // add the image source here
  img.setAttribute("id", "image");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "image");
  document.getElementById("box").append(img);
})

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  document.getElementById("image").remove();
})
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>
    <button id="button5">Surprise</button>
```

Comment: Your codes will work, but it would be simpler to use `innerHTML`: `document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = '<img src="test.jpg" alt="" />';`. You don't even need the `id` attribute; you just need to replace the `innerHTML` every time you clicked on the buttons. On the other hand, you have to set the `type` of `<button>` tags to `type="button"` to prevent the default action, as by default it's a `submit` button, which will submit the current page (probably a reload of the page).

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove classList names that define the CSS you want to show on your element. With the image, just remove the box class and add a new class that has an image as the background.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
const box = document.getElementById('box')

function changeBox(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'button1') {
    box.classList.add('translate')
  } else if (e.target.id === 'button2') {
    box.classList = ''
    box.classList.add('blue')
  } else if (e.target.id === 'button3') {
    box.classList.add('fade')
  } else if (e.target.id === 'button4') {
    box.classList = ''
    box.classList.add('box')
  } else if (e.target.id === 'button5') {
    box.classList.remove('box')
    box.classList.add('img')
  }
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => changeBox(e))
})
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 25px;
}

.img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Stackoverflow_icon.png') no-repeat rgba(0, 230, 230, 0.5);
  margin: 25px;
}

.translate {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade 1s ease-in-out;
}

.blue {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 25px;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

<div id="box" class="box"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
<button id="button5">Surprise</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener(
        "click",
        function () {

            document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = "<img src='./img/1.png' />"

        });
```

or

```
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px">
        <img src="" id="pic">
</div>

document.getElementById("button5").addEventListener(
            "click",
            function () {

                document.getElementById("pic").src = "./img/1.png"

            });
```

Comment: Add a description to your answer.